# jquery UI autocomplete inside a modal ui dialog - suggestions not showing?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using the jquery ui autocomplete widget inside the jquery ui dialog. when i type in the search text, the textbox indents (ui-autocomplet-loading) but does not show any suggestions.

```
var availableTags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"];

$("#company").autocomplete({        
    source : availableTags ,
minLength: 2
});
```

company is the id of the textbox to attach the autocomplete.

i thought it might be a z index so i set this:

```
.ui-autocomplete, .ui-menu, .ui-menu-item {  z-index: 1006; }
```

but it still does not show. i put the autocomplete in a 'regular' page and it works fine.

i am using jquery ui version 1.8.2. any ideas of where to look?

Comment: Try setting the [`appendTo`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option to `"#company"`.  A similar question was asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685558/jqueryui-autocomplete-not-working-with-dialog-and-zindex

Answer (score 83):

I came across this answer when searching for this same issue, however none of the solutions were exactly what I wanted.

Using `appendTo` worked, sorta... The autocomplete items showed up where they were supposed to, however it completely threw my dialog window into a garbled mess of improperly repositioned div elements.

So in my own css file, I created the following:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

I'm sure 1100 is a little overkill, but I just wanted to play it safe.  It works well and conforms with the K.I.S.S. method.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.2 with jQueryUI 1.10.2.

Comment: This is the solution, works like a charm and should be marked as valid ! The modal as "z-index: 1050;" so you need more !

Comment: This solved my issue. It should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time

Comment: Can't get this to work at all, no matter what z-index is set to.

Comment: this solution misses the !important, btw don't mess with jquery-ui z-index because dialog z-index will be changed again to cover the autocomplete after the first usage.

Comment: It works perfectly for me also. After log search and modification.

Comment: It works,  I saved my time! Thank you

Answer (score 15):

When using jQuery UI 1.10, you should not mess around with z-indexes (http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-stack-option). The `appendTo` option works, but will limit the display to the height of the dialog.

To fix it: make sure the autocomplete element is in the correct DOM order with: *autocomplete*.insertAfter(*dialog*.parent())

**Example**

```
 var autoComplete,
     dlg = $("#copy_dialog"),
     input = $(".title", dlg);

 // initialize autocomplete
 input.autocomplete({
     ...
 });

 // get reference to autocomplete element
 autoComplete = input.autocomplete("widget");

 // init the dialog containing the input field
 dlg.dialog({
      ...
 });

 // move the autocomplete element after the dialog in the DOM
 autoComplete.insertAfter(dlg.parent());
```

**Update for z-index problem after dialog click**

The z-index of the autocomplete seems to change after a click on the dialog (as reported by MatteoC). The workaround below seems to fix this:

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv9L7cnr/

```
// initialize autocomplete
input.autocomplete({
    source: ...,
    open: function () {
        autoComplete.zIndex(dlg.zIndex()+1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

I solved it in bootbox like this:

```
$( "#company" ).autocomplete({       
    source : availableTags ,
    appendTo: "#exportOrder"
});
```

You only have to append the result list to your form.

Comment: What does "in bootstrap" mean?

Comment: sorry, I meant "bootbox"

Comment: appendTo was easiest. Thanks

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 12):

In your `autocomplete` implementation, add `appendTo: "#search_modal"`, where *search_modal* is ID of your modal.

Answer (score 7):

for one or multiples autocompletes in the same dialogbox:

```
// init the dialog containing the input field
 $("#dialog").dialog({
      ...
 });

// initialize autocomplete
 $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({        
      source: availableTags,
      minLength: 2
 }).each(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete("widget").insertAfter($("#dialog").parent());
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    $("#company").autocomplete({        
    source : availableTags ,
    appendTo : $('#divName')
    minLength: 2
});
```

Note: $('#divName') divName will be the name of modal body.

EXAMPLE:

```
<form id="exportOrder">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="accountReferenceSearch" placeholder="Type Account Reference to search..." class="form-control" style="width:500px">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

self.AttachAutoComplete = function () {
                    $('#accountReferenceSearch').focus(function () {
                        $('#accountReferenceSearch').autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {},
                            minLength: 2,
                            delay: 300,
                            appendTo: $("#exportOrder")
                        });
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same problem, when it occurred to me:

**Always declare your dialog BEFORE setting autocomplete.**

I’ve switched them around, et voilà!

Autocomplete configure itself around the INPUT you target. Dialog creates new markup and CSS around the container you target. My choices where appearing behind the dialog, or off screen.

Comment: This is the proper answer, forcing z-index around causes only issues on recent versions of jquery ui. Changing the initialization order fixes everything.

Answer (score 3):

I solved adding atribute `z-index:1500` to my divs in
jquery.autocomplete.css because Jquery UI Dialog put z-index between
1000 and 1005

```
ul.auto-complete-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1500;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: to me it's enough to add: 
      ul.ui-autocomplete {z-index: 2100!important;}

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue. Adding this to my css-file solved it for me:

```
.ui-autocomplete-input, .ui-menu, .ui-menu-item {  z-index: 2006; }
```

I first tried your initial z-index value of `1006`, but that didn't work. Increasing the value worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also. I am working in UserFrosting which has bootstrap and select2, but doesn't have jquery-ui in the core. My autocomplete was inside a modal popup where the script tag and `$(document)`.ready are after the html for the modal form. After chasing all kinds of nonexistent conflicts and trying to make select2 (v 4) into a combobox, I went back to the css hack and this worked:

```
.ui-autocomplete {z-index: 1061 !important;}
```

My environment is

- UserFrosting with jquery 1-11.2
- bootstrap-3.3.2,
- bootstrap-modal
- select2 v3.5.1
- jquery-ui-1.11.4 (dot-luv theme)

Comment: this is a duplicate of DondeEstaMiCulo's answer

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. We just updated our css so that z-index is high enough and cannot be overwritten:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

As append to body makes the dropdown child of $window you need to make all dropdown-menu to the new z-index.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding styles in css doesn't work, but after adding `zIndex` property exactly to jQuery ui element constructor, it works like a charm.

Comment: a code snippet example would be nice to understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your javascript and call it from the onload event of the body element:

```
//initialization
function init(){
    var autoSuggestion = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-autocomplete');
    if(autoSuggestion.length > 0){
        autoSuggestion[0].style.zIndex = 1051;
    }
}
```

It works for me :) I got this by looking at the computed style of the modal dialog to see what it's z-index was. So all the function does is grab the auto suggestion box that's created by jquery (by one of it's class names which may be different for you but the idea is still the same) and modify it's css to include a z-index 1 point higher than the z-index of the modal (which was 1050)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
ul.ui-front {
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-
 ***my_modal* : modal id

Use `appendTo` property of `autocomplete`**

`$("#input_box_id").autocomplete({<br>
    source:sourceArray/link,<br>
    appendTo :"#<i>my_modal</i>"<br>
});`

**reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343584/5803974

Answer (score 0):

Johann-S ' answer [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19850) worked for me.

simply add data-focus="false" to the button or link calling the modal like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
 data-toggle="modal" 
 data-focus="false"
data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>
```

This way you don't have to mess with z-indexes or override bootstrap's enforce focus (it's not called)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but after some struggle, I use Firefox to find solution.

> In chrome when any autocomplete view is opened and you want to inspect the element, that will be disappear, when you click on any component.

but

> In Firefox, that will be displayed continuously so we can find the view at all.

and I did the same thing with that, and I found a class which is having z-index

```
z-index: 1000
```

so I just changed this to more like

```
.pac-container{
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

might be this z-index solution will not work for you all, but I am sure the feature of Firefox will definitely help you to find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue , It has been resolved by adding bellow styles :

```
.ui-autocomplete { position: absolute;  cursor: default;z-index:30!important;}  
.modal-dialog {pointer-events:auto !important;}
```