# Auto complete Appearing behind the Modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using simple jquery popup and Auto complete of  [jQuery Auto complete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) .The code of Auto complete is something like this.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: NameArray
});
```

where tags is the textbox id and NameArray is Array of string.However this code in the Modal pop-up like this-

```
function openFilterPopUp() {

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: NameArray
    });
    $("#openFilterPopUp").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
            Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });

}
```

The data for Autocomplete is appearing fine but its appearing behind the popup.Please Help. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add appendTo property of autocomplete

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: NameArray,
    appendTo : _parentElement
});
```

_parentElement can be your modal body

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted because this solved my problem within seconds of searching for a solution. You can use an element's ID in the appendTo option like so `appendTo: "#your_element_id"`.  Just to add the official documentation for the appendTo option: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

Answer (score 2):

I try this code and success :

```html
$("#tagsname").autocomplete({
    appendTo : "#modalform",
    source: DataArray
    
});
```