# Autocomplete jquery gives me words under bootstrap panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete function with jquery.
The function is working great but i have problems showing the autocomplete words.

I'm using autocomplete function on input which is in bootstrap panel class and the words are shown behind the panel but I want to show the words inside the panel.

```
<div class="modal-body" align="center">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchid" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see on the Screenshot below the words are behind the panel.
[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to find the main container div of the suggestions and then give it a css property `z-index:999999;` This will bring it up front.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto complete Appearing behind the Modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343508/auto-complete-appearing-behind-the-modal-popup)